# Store @Timed annotation values in a database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In my application there is an endpoint:

```
    @Timed(value = "project.time")
    @GetMapping("/project/{projectId}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ProjectProjection>> getTopicsBySupporterProject(
        @PathVariable("projectId") Long projectId) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(projectService.getProjectById(projectId);
    }
```

It works fine, the "project.time" endpoint shows me the information what I needed.  But is there any way to save the values from "project.time" metric endpoint?